# substitute variable in différential equation in maple

Tags: maple

I use this code in Maple:

```
Ur := unapply(simplify(subs(r = r/a^(1/2), z = z/a, ur0(r, z))/a^(1/2)), r, z)
```

I obtain this result:

[image: equation]

Is there a way for Maple to understand that `diff(p(r/sqrt(a)),r/sqrt(a)) = 1/sqrt(a)*diff(p(r),r)`?

Comment: I think you're in the wrong place ... what you are asking is to explain math, not really programming.

Comment: It's not math. I can find the result on paper  but it's a lot of works... 
Maple give me diff((p(r/sqrt(a)),r/sqrt(a)) in the result, so it stays a lot simplification to do and I need to use this expression (derivate 2 times, so I obtain very longs and awful expression that I need to simplify ...).

Comment: I assume you meant `1/sqrt(a)*diff(p(r),r)` and not `sqrt(a)*diff(p(r),r)` in your second code.

Comment: I inlined the image for readability

Comment: @kafka I couldn't help but notice that you removed my answer's "accepted" status. Is there anything unsatisfying about the answer? If so, I would happily correct that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the reason of the removing ... I can't vote because I have less than 15 in reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to differentiate with regards to an algebraic expression you can use the `algsubs` command together with the inert `Diff` command and then `subs` back the expression if the function is differentiable.

```
Diff(p(r/sqrt(a)),r/sqrt(a));  # Equation
algsubs(r/sqrt(a) = x,%);      # Substitute derivative variable       (1)
p:=x -> x^2;                   # Define function to differentiate
value(%%);                     # Evaluate the differential (1)
subs(x=r/sqrt(a),%);           # Substitute back in again
```